# Differences between classes in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, class, difference

Are there any major differences between classes in C and C++? e.g. Different coding conventions, different ways of providing access to members, mechanisms that are only available in one language and not the other, etc.

Comment: Why did you not even bother to [Google this question](https://www.google.com/search?q=difference+between+C+and+C%2B%2B&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb) there are HUNDREDS of articles on the differences between C and C++.

Comment: Well the main difference is that using C classes is pretty hard, given the fact that it does not have them.

Comment: I suggest cutting your losses and deleting this ... question.

Answer (score 0):

There are no classes in C... Maybe you meant structs, but these are just a collection of data (all public) in C.